# How to write a function finding even numbers in list on F#

Tags: function, recursion, f#, f#-interactive

Hello guys so i have a problem about finding even numbers in the list.
Im so new in F# and i need to find even numbers in the list with function.

I have the real question:

//Given is a list of integers. Write a recursive function that returns a pair of lists: a list of even numbers
//and a list of numbers divisible by three. For example, for the list [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6] we should get ([2; 4; 6], [3; 6]).

I tried this :

```
let list1 = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10]
let evens list1 =
   let isEven x = x % 2 = 0  
                              
   List.filter isEven list1
```

But its not working. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

What you've got is correct for finding even numbers. The only thing missing is that you need to call your `evens` function, passing it `list1`, like this: `evens list1`.

Keep in mind that the parameters of a function are different from its arguments. In this case, you've called both the parameter and the argument `list1`, which may be confusing you.

Here's a complete version, using two different names for clarity:

```
let myList = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10]
let evens anyList =
   let isEven x = x % 2 = 0  
   List.filter isEven anyList
printfn "%A" (evens myList)
```

Once you understand how this works, you can try solving the full problem you mentioned.